# R: Visualizing "Linked" Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I am using R and am trying to re-create something like this picture:

I did some research and saw that the "ggforce" library (https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_parallel_sets.html) in R allows the user to make similar styles of plots (plots using the "first name", "middle name" and "last name" - these plots show that the "first name" is really common, the "first name and the middle name" is a bit less common, and the "first name, middle name and last name" is much less common):

```
library(ggforce)
library(reshape2)

 name_data <- data.frame(
    
    "First_Name" = c("John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "James", "James", "Adam", "Adam", "Henry"),
    "Middle_Name" = c("Claude", "Claude", "Claude", "Smith", "Smith", "Peters", "Stevens", "Stevens", "Ford", "Tom", "Frank"),
    "Last Name " = c("Tony", "Tony", "Frank", "Carson", "Phil", "Lewis", "Eric", "David", "Roberts", "Scott", "Xavier")
)

name_data$ID <- seq.int(nrow(name_data))
 
data <- reshape2::melt(name_data)
data <- gather_set_data(name_data)

ggplot(name_data, aes( id = value, split = First_Name, value = value)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes( alpha = 0.3, axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = 'white'))
```

But this returns the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found
```

Can someone please show me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in ggplot aes function is the x-axis variable. In the example you provided, that was `x=survived` (which was probably set earlier in the example). You need to specify an x-axis variable, in this case perhaps it is `x=City`? i.e. try:

```
ggplot(name_data, aes(x=City, id=ID, ...
```

**EDIT:**
OK it looks like you first need to have a count of the different name combinations (this already existed in the titanic data example as the value column). You can do this with the `aggregate` function:

```
name_counts=aggregate(name_data$ID,
                      by=list(First_Name=name_data$First_Name,
                              Middle_Name=name_data$Middle_Name,
                              Last_Name=name_data$Last.Name.),
                      FUN=length)
names(name_counts)[4] = 'value'
```

this gives a count of each combination of first, middle and last names. At this point, run the `gather_set_data` function:

```
name_counts_gathered = gather_set_data(name_counts, 1:3)
```

Now, you can plot using `ggplot` and `geom_parallel_sets`:

```
ggplot(name_counts_gathered) +
    geom_parallel_sets(aes(x=x,id=id,split=y,value=value))
```

The `gather_set_data` function adds the id, x and y columns as required by the plotting function.

I'm not entirely sure how you want the plot to look but you can hopefully now play around with the plotting labels and options.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just realized that "city" is not needed for this graph, so I removed it from the data. I can add an "id" to this dataset, will that work? thank you so much

Comment: i made some changes, can you please take a look at it now? thank you!

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! If you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324822/correctly-specifying-logical-conditions-in-r thank you so much!